# Convert image to pencil sketch in android

Tags: java, android, image-processing, sketching

I have to convert an image to a pencil sketch in android.

I used the concepts of the cataleno framework and colorDodge function mentioned in one of the previous questions.

This is my function:

```
public void onBwClick(View v) {
    Bitmap bm = ((BitmapDrawable) mImageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

    FastBitmap fb = new FastBitmap(bm);

    Grayscale g = new Grayscale();
    g.applyInPlace(fb);

    Invert i = new Invert();
    i.applyInPlace(fb);

    GaussianBlur gb = new GaussianBlur();
    gb.applyInPlace(fb);

    FastBitmap xb = new FastBitmap(bm);
    Grayscale gs = new Grayscale();
    g.applyInPlace(xb);

    Bitmap result = colorDodgeBlend(fb.toBitmap(), xb.toBitmap());

    mImageView.setImageBitmap(result);
}
```

This is the colorDodgeBlend function:

```
public Bitmap colorDodgeBlend(Bitmap source, Bitmap layer) {
    Log.d("", "logger enter colorDodgeBlend");
    Bitmap base = source.copy(Config.ARGB_8888, true);
    Bitmap blend = layer.copy(Config.ARGB_8888, false);

    IntBuffer buffBase = IntBuffer.allocate(base.getWidth()
            * base.getHeight());
    base.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffBase);
    buffBase.rewind();

    IntBuffer buffBlend = IntBuffer.allocate(blend.getWidth()
            * blend.getHeight());
    blend.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffBlend);
    buffBlend.rewind();

    IntBuffer buffOut = IntBuffer.allocate(base.getWidth()
            * base.getHeight());
    buffOut.rewind();

    while (buffOut.position() < buffOut.limit()) {
        int filterInt = buffBlend.get();
        int srcInt = buffBase.get();

        int redValueFilter = Color.red(filterInt);
        int greenValueFilter = Color.green(filterInt);
        int blueValueFilter = Color.blue(filterInt);

        int redValueSrc = Color.red(srcInt);
        int greenValueSrc = Color.green(srcInt);
        int blueValueSrc = Color.blue(srcInt);

        int redValueFinal = colordodge(redValueFilter, redValueSrc);
        int greenValueFinal = colordodge(greenValueFilter, greenValueSrc);
        int blueValueFinal = colordodge(blueValueFilter, blueValueSrc);

        int pixel = Color.argb(255, redValueFinal, greenValueFinal,
                blueValueFinal);

        float[] hsv = new float[3];
        Color.colorToHSV(pixel, hsv);
        hsv[1] = 0.0f;
        float top = VALUE_TOP; // Setting this as 0.95f gave the best result so far 
        if (hsv[2] <= top) {
            hsv[2] = 0.0f;
        } else {
            hsv[2] = 1.0f;
        }
        pixel = Color.HSVToColor(hsv);

        buffOut.put(pixel);
    }

    buffOut.rewind();

    base.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffOut);
    blend.recycle();
    Log.d("", "logger executed colorDodgeBlend");
    return base;
}
```

Finally this is the output I am getting:
!https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9LDDNqlgTC1U3E3QXdiejk1Q28/edit?usp=sharing

This is what i desire:
!https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9LDDNqlgTC1QkFPSmJFOXMyaUU/edit?usp=sharing

Kindly help me out in this.

Comment: The catalano framework:http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/656059/Catalano-Framework ; the previous question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9826273/photo-image-to-sketch-algorithm

Answer (score 2):

You Need to do Below 2 Things.
**1..** **Use This Code for Blur Effect With Radius = 10 or more**.

```
public Bitmap fastblur(Bitmap sentBitmap, int radius) {

        Bitmap bitmap = sentBitmap.copy(sentBitmap.getConfig(), true);

        if (radius < 1) {
            return (null);
        }

        int w = bitmap.getWidth();
        int h = bitmap.getHeight();

        int[] pix = new int[w * h];
        Log.e("pix", w + " " + h + " " + pix.length);
        bitmap.getPixels(pix, 0, w, 0, 0, w, h);

        int wm = w - 1;
        int hm = h - 1;
        int wh = w * h;
        int div = radius + radius + 1;

        int r[] = new int[wh];
        int g[] = new int[wh];
        int b[] = new int[wh];
        int rsum, gsum, bsum, x, y, i, p, yp, yi, yw;
        int vmin[] = new int[Math.max(w, h)];

        int divsum = (div + 1) >> 1;
        divsum *= divsum;
        int dv[] = new int[256 * divsum];
        for (i = 0; i < 256 * divsum; i++) {
            dv[i] = (i / divsum);
        }

        yw = yi = 0;

        int[][] stack = new int[div][3];
        int stackpointer;
        int stackstart;
        int[] sir;
        int rbs;
        int r1 = radius + 1;
        int routsum, goutsum, boutsum;
        int rinsum, ginsum, binsum;

        for (y = 0; y < h; y++) {
            rinsum = ginsum = binsum = routsum = goutsum = boutsum = rsum = gsum = bsum = 0;
            for (i = -radius; i <= radius; i++) {
                p = pix[yi + Math.min(wm, Math.max(i, 0))];
                sir = stack[i + radius];
                sir[0] = (p & 0xff0000) >> 16;
                sir[1] = (p & 0x00ff00) >> 8;
                sir[2] = (p & 0x0000ff);
                rbs = r1 - Math.abs(i);
                rsum += sir[0] * rbs;
                gsum += sir[1] * rbs;
                bsum += sir[2] * rbs;
                if (i > 0) {
                    rinsum += sir[0];
                    ginsum += sir[1];
                    binsum += sir[2];
                } else {
                    routsum += sir[0];
                    goutsum += sir[1];
                    boutsum += sir[2];
                }
            }
            stackpointer = radius;

            for (x = 0; x < w; x++) {

                r[yi] = dv[rsum];
                g[yi] = dv[gsum];
                b[yi] = dv[bsum];

                rsum -= routsum;
                gsum -= goutsum;
                bsum -= boutsum;

                stackstart = stackpointer - radius + div;
                sir = stack[stackstart % div];

                routsum -= sir[0];
                goutsum -= sir[1];
                boutsum -= sir[2];

                if (y == 0) {
                    vmin[x] = Math.min(x + radius + 1, wm);
                }
                p = pix[yw + vmin[x]];

                sir[0] = (p & 0xff0000) >> 16;
                sir[1] = (p & 0x00ff00) >> 8;
                sir[2] = (p & 0x0000ff);

                rinsum += sir[0];
                ginsum += sir[1];
                binsum += sir[2];

                rsum += rinsum;
                gsum += ginsum;
                bsum += binsum;

                stackpointer = (stackpointer + 1) % div;
                sir = stack[(stackpointer) % div];

                routsum += sir[0];
                goutsum += sir[1];
                boutsum += sir[2];

                rinsum -= sir[0];
                ginsum -= sir[1];
                binsum -= sir[2];

                yi++;
            }
            yw += w;
        }
        for (x = 0; x < w; x++) {
            rinsum = ginsum = binsum = routsum = goutsum = boutsum = rsum = gsum = bsum = 0;
            yp = -radius * w;
            for (i = -radius; i <= radius; i++) {
                yi = Math.max(0, yp) + x;

                sir = stack[i + radius];

                sir[0] = r[yi];
                sir[1] = g[yi];
                sir[2] = b[yi];

                rbs = r1 - Math.abs(i);

                rsum += r[yi] * rbs;
                gsum += g[yi] * rbs;
                bsum += b[yi] * rbs;

                if (i > 0) {
                    rinsum += sir[0];
                    ginsum += sir[1];
                    binsum += sir[2];
                } else {
                    routsum += sir[0];
                    goutsum += sir[1];
                    boutsum += sir[2];
                }

                if (i < hm) {
                    yp += w;
                }
            }
            yi = x;
            stackpointer = radius;
            for (y = 0; y < h; y++) {
                // Preserve alpha channel: ( 0xff000000 & pix[yi] )
                pix[yi] = (0xff000000 & pix[yi]) | (dv[rsum] << 16)
                        | (dv[gsum] << 8) | dv[bsum];

                rsum -= routsum;
                gsum -= goutsum;
                bsum -= boutsum;

                stackstart = stackpointer - radius + div;
                sir = stack[stackstart % div];

                routsum -= sir[0];
                goutsum -= sir[1];
                boutsum -= sir[2];

                if (x == 0) {
                    vmin[y] = Math.min(y + r1, hm) * w;
                }
                p = x + vmin[y];

                sir[0] = r[p];
                sir[1] = g[p];
                sir[2] = b[p];

                rinsum += sir[0];
                ginsum += sir[1];
                binsum += sir[2];

                rsum += rinsum;
                gsum += ginsum;
                bsum += binsum;

                stackpointer = (stackpointer + 1) % div;
                sir = stack[stackpointer];

                routsum += sir[0];
                goutsum += sir[1];
                boutsum += sir[2];

                rinsum -= sir[0];
                ginsum -= sir[1];
                binsum -= sir[2];

                yi += w;
            }
        }

        Log.e("pix", w + " " + h + " " + pix.length);
        bitmap.setPixels(pix, 0, w, 0, 0, w, h);

        return (bitmap);
    }
```

**2.. Remove Below Code from colorDodgeBlend Function**

```
float[] hsv = new float[3];
        Color.colorToHSV(pixel, hsv);
        hsv[1] = 0.0f;
        float top = VALUE_TOP; // Setting this as 0.95f gave the best result so far 
        if (hsv[2] <= top) {
            hsv[2] = 0.0f;
        } else {
            hsv[2] = 1.0f;
        }
        pixel = Color.HSVToColor(hsv);
```