# Convert image to sketch and then cartoonify?

Tags: java, android, image, image-processing

My aim is to let the user take a selfie from my app and then apply different image processing algorithms to convert it in a cartoon type image. I followed the algo [written here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9826273/photo-image-to-sketch-algorithm), and then also used the method written just below the chosen answer to convert black and white sketch to colored image that should look like cartoon. Every thing is ok except that after applying Gaussian Blur , the image becomes too hazy and unclear. Here is the image output:
[image]

Any advice how I can make it more clear? Like [shown in this link.](http://www.photoshopessentials.com/photo-effects/portrait-to-sketch/) I know they used Photoshop , but I want to achieve it with Java and Android.

PS: I found all the image processing methods [from here](https://xjaphx.wordpress.com/learning/tutorials/). Plus the method [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21575358/convert-image-to-pencil-sketch-in-android) (the one below the chosen answer), what could be the ideal values in the arguments?

Comment: I can't offer a full answer to this, but isn't Gaussian blur supposed to make an image hazy and unclear?

Comment: Yeah , that's what I am thinking , but according to the answer and all over the internet everyone suggests to use the same algo. Even after that I tried different things with the colorDodgeBlend() method. The closest I came to a sketch like image was when I applied Gaussian Blur first

Comment: The bilateral filter is another common way to make something look cartoonish.  Have a look here: http://kucg.korea.ac.kr/seminar/2008/src/PA-07-12.pdf

Comment: [How to cartoon-ify an image programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1357403/2545927) might be of help...

Comment: @kkuilla that's the post I linked in my question.

Comment: I compared the links in your question with that one and they are different as far as I can see but it's not any of my concern. I was just trying to get your some hints to move forward.

Comment: @kkuilla my bad... I checked out so many links I got confused. Anyway , thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[cartoonifying image](https://github.com/davemk99/Cartoonify-Image/)

If you have a basic knowledge of C++, you can port this app for your need.
This application works real time. If you want to non-real time,than you can use bilateral filter against two medianBlurs at the bottom of function. That will give better results, but bad performance. But you need to use OpenCV in your application. If you want to make application with more functions, I will suggest you to do it.