# Android draw path follow the image

Tags: android

I need to draw path following the image, I have that Image and already convert that to bitmap. Is there any method to do this or any algorithm that I can use?Thanks a lot for your help...

Regards

Comment: Can you please be a bit clear? *I need to draw path following the image* means?

Comment: Post your code snapshot xml file Everything..

Comment: If we have an Image, and we want to draw path or line following that image, is this possible?something like we need to change an Image to be just contain line that follows the pattern of that image.

Comment: So you want to just show the border of image, right? Something like we see in hidden object games? (i.e. shape of image.)

Comment: Yes, similar with that. the border of the image, but not only the outline. actually, I have a fingerprint image, and I want to convert it to path or line so it will be more easy to track the different between a finger with another.

Comment: Cool. Never did such thing. You could check if answers on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9826273) help you in starting.