# Looking for Java library convert picture to cartoon

Tags: java, image

Anyone know any existing library in the market? or open source project? The library should be able to convert picture or any images to cartoon-like image.

Please suggest me if you have use anything like that before.

Comment: Hi, did you find. I am sorry that this question was closed.

Comment: @arqam, sorry, I couldn't find it at that time.

Comment: so even if I don't use any library do you have any approach as in what all to do so that I can get the result through image processing algorithms. Just for the face part.

Comment: @arqam, sorry, I am not good in image processing, but I refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/a/1357443/1542363, you maybe able to find some `Gaussian Blur` implementation to try out the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on what you mean by *cartoon-like*. Sometimes, applying some filters and doing some other minor operations might give you a decent result. If that is what you are after, you could use something like [JavaCV](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/) (which is a wrapper for [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/).

This library should provide you with access to some graphical tools which should allow you to manipulate the image to obtain what you are after.

If on the other hand you are after a caricature type of cartoon, I think that you would need to use some AI techniques since caricatures usually involve the exaggeration of some physical feature, and for that, you would need AI to extract the said feature.

Finally, you can take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357403/how-to-cartoon-ify-an-image-programmatically) previous SO thread which contains some other pointers on how you can convert an image to a cartoon.

Comment: Hi, I am not after caricature type of cartoon. In JavaCV, is there any function I can just convert the picture to cartoon image in just few line of code? I never touch any picture-related-term before.

Comment: @GMsoF: If that is the case then you could refer to the link I posted. It should put you in the right direction. The library I mentioned should also be enough for what you are after.

Comment: So, which mean I have to adjust the color and line pattern until I got the desired effect? Any library out there to convert the thing without having any image-related knowledge?

Comment: @GMsoF: One of the links in the SO page seems to point to a library which might help. I think you should give it a look....