# How to recreate this edge smoothing image filter?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, edge-detection, imagefilter

I'm trying to recreate a filter found in the app.

I've tried Local adaptive binarize, curvature flow, anisotropic diffusion but couldn't get a similar effect.

The original image (public image from Flickr):
[image]

Filtered image with low smoothing:
[image]

Filtered image with more smoothing (look at the eyebrows):
[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to SO. It is difficult to help you because you have not specified what effect you want to achieve. Can you post the photo showing the desired effect?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. There are the links to 3 images, please open them and have a look.

Comment: I've seen them but don't understand what photo presents the effect that you want to achieve (low smoothing or more smoothing). Please also provide the code that you use to filter the image.

Comment: I'd like to have a function with a certain parameter that would generate each of them for different values of this parameter.

Comment: Are you looking for a "cartoonify" filter? If so, this SO post may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357403/how-to-cartoon-ify-an-image-programmatically